# Argument of type 'string | User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material

in the following code, present in angular-material examples :
https://stackblitz.com/angular/gorglnbmork?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith({} as User),
        map(user => user && typeof user === 'object' ? user.name : user),
        map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.options.slice())
      );
  }
```

I have the following error on this.filter(name) : Argument of type 'string | User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

why ? What can be done to avoid it ?

Added to this post after :

I corrected the error by doing the following change to the parameter of filter :

```
filter(name: string | User): User[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
}
```

but I don't know what string | User mean and after that there is an issue on name.toLowerCase() as string | User has no method toLowerCase()

Thank you for your feedbacks !

Comment: Anybody else notice that the linked site hosting the angular IDE is built on react?

Answer (score 0):

Your users have the type User which is not a string. The problem is in your

```
displayFn(user: User): string {
    return user ? user.name : user.name;
  }
```

You want the returned value to be of type User but in the case of "!user" you return user which is from type User and not string. 
So you can specify the type of your function to be string | User or try to return always a string.

Comment: the line concerned is this.filter(name) and not displayFn.

Comment: I corrected the error by doing the following change to the parameter of filter :

Comment: filter(name: string | User): User[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

Comment: but parameter string| User doesn't mean anything to me and after there is an issue on name.toLowerCase() as string | User don't have the method toLowerCase